# html Como poner dobles comillas en una url con consulta

Tags: html

Para que se entienda si busco dos palabras en mi web, la url es de este modo:

> /phpbb_topic_tagging.php?mode=search&tag="Palabra1+Palabra2"

Quiero poner links estáticos  de búsquedas pre establecidas, pero no me resulta al poner dobles comillas, ni tampoco comillas simples con \

```
<a href="/phpbb_topic_tagging.php?mode=search&tag="Palabra1+Palabra2"">Palabra1 Palabra2</a>
```

Si no uso comillas el buscador no funciona correctamente ya que deja de buscar las dos palabras juntas.

Alguna idea?

Gracias

P.D: tiene que ser en html

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando `&quot;` no deberías tener problemas.

```
<a href="/phpbb_topic_tagging.php
mode=search&tag=&quot;Palabra1+Palabra2&quot;">Palabra1 Palabra2</a>
```

Saludos